# how to insert data in a column of apache hive

Tags: hive

I have some data in a hive table and I added a new column in hive. Now I want to add some value in new column cells according to by key. How I can achieve it? My hive version is 0.11. For some reasons I cannot update version

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more, like what is the table structure ? At what position you want to add new column ? How do want to load data to that table(from other table or from a file) ?

Comment: My data is in a file and My column is at last position of columns

Answer (score 0):

This might sound naive if you already have done data migrations. Anyways,
How are you getting the new columns data ? Assuming its separate file which can be loaded to another temp table with Key , New Column values.
Then do a join with your existing table and populate data to 3rd table. and last insert overwrite your main table with the data from 3rd table with new column updated.

A - existing table with new column but no data updated.
B - temp table with Key and New column data
C - Select all columns from A and new column from B FROM A join B on A.key=B.key
Final - Insert overwrite Table A from table C

Hope this helps. Sorry if are you looking for any tool to do this in more easier way,this might be a lengthier approach.